# "Add content" button on related content node?

Tags: 7, nodes, organic-groups

Let's say I have 2 content types "Shopping center" and "Shop".

"Shopping center" is a OG group.
"Shop" has node reference field "Shopping center".

I would like to allow moderators to add shops to shopping centers on the shopping center node screen.

How to add "add shop" button on "Shopping center" node view ?

Comment: I am sure it is possible to do without any custom coding. I have already seen this before using contributed modules only. I cannot remember how to set this up :(

Comment: Any ideas how to do this using Organic Groups and Drupal 7 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how OG handles the "This Shop belongs to that Shopping Center" relation, but for a Node reference field there is the [Node Reference URL Widget](http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_url) which can be used for this. It provides both the *widget* that wil sets the node reference field value from the URL and the link to create a new referencing node from the referenced node page.

Comment: It seems that Node Reference URL Widget is supposed to work with OG (ref: https://drupal.org/node/1121656), if it doesn',t consider reporting an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing redundant work by having a node reference field. If "shop" is set up as a group post, you should be able to add new shops when in a shopping center context. There should be some kind of "group options" block that will give you these options. (Haven't done this exact thing in 7 yet but it must be similar to the way it works in 6).

Comment: You might be right here, what I am looking for could be OG specific or node reference specific. What matters is that this should work. I still don't remember where to configure this...

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Contextual Administration](http://drupal.org/project/context_admin) module may help you to create that.

In the project page, you can also find the link to a really nice video about using the module.